# Opening a java program via image file,

Tags: java

I have a java program that can display image files, and I want to make it my default program that opens image files, or even just open the image in my program when I click `open with…`.

So can anyone tell me if there is a way to:

1. Open my java program via `open with…`
2. Get the file that was opening my program?

Comment: this is probably via the OS . like windows has an option to choose default program 2 open w/

Comment: Open With, Choose default program, Browse and find the executable of your program.

Comment: Open with… does not open my .jar file

Comment: **and** I want to know how to get the file within my java program after opening,

Comment: Maybe generating a EXE from your jar or maybe with a BAT